# How to connect a folder placed inside Angular assets in a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I try to achieve the following with Angular and a Node.js cloud function (Firebase):

1. Placing an entire folder with many files (2MB) to the Angular /assets/ folder.
2. Let the user input some data to change specific text content of some files
3. Calling the Cloud function with an HTTP Request and send the user data
4. **Access this folder inside the cloud function**
5. Cloning the entire folder to a temporary directory and work on the cloned files with Node.JS by replacing some content strings in some files
6. Sending the URL from the new manipulated folder back to the user

In general I have problems to understand how I could I create a connection between the cloud function and the folder I want to work with. Both, the Angular application and also the Cloud Functions, are hosted on Firebase. When I understand how I can connect with the folder, the other points would be no problem.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to?

Comment: Could you explain the use case behind the things you want to achieve (without the defined steps)? That would make it easier to give good guidance. 

Specifically, I do not understand why you want to use the asset folder to store and transfer dynamic data.

Comment: I'm working on a generator for a complete PHP project for which the user can fill some fields before. After submitting, I call an API that changes some strings in the file to match the input of the user. After finishing, he can download the individual file as ZIP. Currently I do it with another API on a server where the files are located directly. But I have no idea how to store some files directly in Firebase which are accessable from the cloud functions then  I think the storage is not the right use case for this..